# In the simple linear regression model, ˆb is the sum of independent normally distributed random variables.

Tags: statistics, regression

$y = \hat{a} + \hat{b}x$ is the regression model equation. is it true that .''In the simple linear regression model, $\hat{b}$ is the sum of independent normally
distributed random variables? and why?

Comment: It's unclear what `^b` is in your question. Please edit and add more context. Moreover, it looks like you're quoting homework. If that's the case, consider mentioning that you are and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: it is about the regression equation

Comment: I've edited the equation format for clarity. Please let us know if this is what you meant to say

Comment: yes,that was what i meant

Comment: i edited, now could you help me?